# Tables for Articles, dealers and units

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have 3 Models:

```
Article (:title)
  has_many :units
Dealer (:name, :adress)
  has_many :units
Unit (:price, :dealer_id, :article_id)
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :dealer
```

I'm not sure if I'm perfectly right with my tables and I'm not sure if I should use has_many :through or just has:many and belongs to? What is exactly the difference?

And how exactly would the rails queries look like?

```
Article.find(:name => "Cheese").units
Article.find(:name => "cheese").units.minimum('price').dealer
```

Would such complex rails queries work in this kind of relationsship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare the has_many through like this:

```
Unit (:price, :dealer_id, :article_id)
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :dealer

Article (:title)
  has_many :units
  has_many :dealers, through: :units

Dealer (:name, :adress)
  has_many :units
  has_many :articles, through: :units
```

Using the `has_many :objects, through: :relation` let you access to the objects of a particular entry:

```
@dealer.articles
# and
@article.dealers
```

This `has_many through:` is a different way to do a `has_and_belongs_to_many`: it allows additional attributes and validations on the join model **([Ruby style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide))**

Doing the following will generate 2 queries to the DB:

```
Article.find(:name => "Cheese").units
```

We know that the Unit model has an attribute `article_id`. The best in this case would be (assuming you know the article's id):

```
Unit.where(article_id: article.id)
```

This generate only one query to the DB.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot. How about creating a new Article, a new Unit and adding it to a dealer at the same time?


https://gist.github.com/4446901



Is this the best way to do something like this?

Comment: My code (at gist) is creating two unit lines. One with an dealer_id and one without one but with the price. I think its because the "@article = @dealer.articles.create" already creates the unit relation, but how do I specify a price for the unit?

Comment: I posted a comment on your gist

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you :) I think I will try to do my database queries step by step like your last gist. It's much easier for me.